# Why cannot std::stol be converted to a std::function object?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, constructor, type-conversion

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    function<long(const string&, size_t, int)> fn = stol;
}
```

The code above cannot be compiled as expected with the following error:

> error : no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::function<long (const std::string &, std::size_t, int)>' (aka 'function<long (const basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> > &, unsigned long long, int)>')

Comment: To begin with, [this `std::stol` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) should be helpful. Note the arguments, and compare them with yours.

Comment: The second parameter of `std::stol()` is a `size_t*` pointer, not a `size_t` value like you have it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two reasons:

1. The second argument of `std::stol` has type `std::size_t*`, not `std::size_t`.
2. `std::stol` is overloaded to also accept `const std::wstring&` as its first argument.

You would have to write:

```
function<long(const string&, size_t*, int)> fn =
  static_cast<long(*)(const string&, size_t*, int)>(stol);
```

Addendum (July, 2019): In C++20, the solution described above becomes invalid (see comments). You have to use a lambda instead.

Comment: There is *slightly* less repetition if you write it as: `typedef long sig(const std::string&, size_t*, int);
    const auto pstoll = static_cast<sig*>(std::stol);
    const std::function<sig> fn = pstoll;`  - but it is still pretty nasty.

Comment: Oh, I suppose: `typedef long sig(const std::string&, size_t*, int); const std::function<sig> fn = static_cast<sig*>(std::stol);` also works.

Comment: @L.F. It seems that new wording was added in C++20, so this answer was correct at the time when it was written. I'll add a note about how it breaks in C++20.